# How to run docker command in docker container for appveyor server docker builds?

Tags: docker, appveyor

I'm setting up a new appveyor server and trying to build docker images with using the docker build feature. But when I try to run docker commands in my custom build container, got the error that shown below.

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

I think the appveyor server should run our custom build containers with the volume option that point the docker.sock.

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker name-of-the-custom-image bash
```

Comment: Can you just give it a try. Running docker run command with --privileged flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify Docker cloud settings under Account -> Build environment and put the following into Custom Docker command arguments:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```

https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/24364-how-to-run-docker-command-in-docker-container-for-appveyor-server-docker-builds